# (Nested) IF statement to calculate MEAN in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I have collected values for several test persons and for different tasks, and I want to calculate the AVERAGE and STDEV for each of the test persons for each task. This is what my table looks like: 
[image]

I want to calculate the AVERAGE and STDEV for each person and each task, and I want to do this with one formula and (as it is possible) no "help columns" or by filtering manually. On a different sheet (called "analysis") I have another table to show me the summarized data. It looks like this: 
[image]

In the highlighted cell, I want to add the summarized AVERAGE (and there's a similar table for STDEV). So far, I tried:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(analysis!B1=values!$A$2:$A$13,IF(analysis!A2=values!$B$2:$B$13,values!$C$2:$C$13)))
```

... and many other variants of this, like switching the positions and so on. I also tried COUNTIF in the IF loop (that's a solution I found for somehow similar problems, but then I didn't find a way to tell Excel to just calculate the values where the test person and task was actually correct.

I guess it's because the IF statement doesn't work with an array, but this is just a guess. I searched for similar questions in different portals, but the main problem was that I really need Excel to return the correct values in order to calculate the mean - just returning TRUE or FALSE won't work (or at least I don't know how). I would appreciate every advice or solution you have!

Comment: Apart from me mixing up "mean" and "average" when asking the question, it turned out to be a bug. I always got "0" as a result for this, because Excel somehow always changed the sheet for the average calculation to be the "analysis" sheet, not the "values". Of course, there were no entries, and the result was "0" then. I changed it back manually and immediately got the results. Thanks to the helpers anyways, I always appreciate the help I get in this community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not have a function called "mean". It uses the "Average" function.

Also, your formulas are array formulas and need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter (see screenshot for result).

```
=AVERAGE(IF(Analysis!B$1=Values!$A$2:$A$13,IF(Analysis!$A2=Values!$B$2:$B$13,Values!$C$2:$C$13)))
```

[image]

The same approach will apply to a StDev function.

Comment: I mixed the words up when I translated the German UI - I meant "average" of course! Thanks for your help. It turned out that it was actually a bug in Excel: It always redirected the columns for the average calculation back to my "analysis" sheet, which was of course empty. I changed it back manually and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is fine except that you need to change MEAN to AVERAGE. Also if you want to be able to pull the formula down and across to select the four combinations of Task and Test Person, you need to fix the row and column with $ signs

```
=AVERAGE(IF(analysis!B$1=values!$A$2:$A$13,IF(analysis!$A2=values!$B$2:$B$13,values!$C$2:$C$13)))
```

Make sure that you enter it as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

You can then get the standard deviation in exactly the same way replacing AVERAGE by STDEV or STDEV.S (for sample SD, the usual one) or STDEV.P (for population SD).